# give template tags inside jquery prepend function

Tags: python, jquery, django

my jquery:

```
else if(json.event == "Follow Notify"){
   console.log(json.sender)
 $("#not").prepend('<li class="media">'+
                    '<a href="javascript:;">'+
                        '<div class="media-left">'+
                            '<i class="fa fa-bug media-object bg- 
                          silver-darker"></i>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="media-body">'+
                            '<h6 class="media- 
                       heading">'+json.notification'+
                            '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle text- 
                           danger"></i></h6>'+
                            '<p>'+json.notification+'</p>'+
                            '<a href="{% url "student:accept_follow" 
          pk=request.user.id notify='+json.sender+' %}">Accept</a>'+
                            '<a href="{% url "student:reject_follow" 
          pk=request.user.id notify='+json.sender+' %}">Reject</a>'+
                            '</div></a></li>')
}
```

I want to prepend html code with django url tags ..Im receiving a json and parsing it with json.sender..but it seems its taking it as a string .HOw do i propelry allow django template tags inside this jquery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

You're better off having those URLs in the JSON payload, e.g.

```
return JSONResponse({
  "sender": sender,
  "accept_follow_url": resolve_url("student:accept_follow", pk=request.user.id, notify=sender),
  "..."
})
```